# Is $X\times Y$ with lexicographical ordering order-isomorphic with $X\times Y$ with anti-lexicographical ordering?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I am trying to figure out if $X\times Y$ with lexicographical ordering order-isomorphic with $X\times Y$ with anti-lexicographical ordering? Is it true?

Comment: Presumably $X$ and $Y$ are given as ordered sets? If so, you should specify that. Have you tried it with $X=\{0,1\}$ and $Y=\Bbb N$, the natural numbers?

Answer (score 1):

They're not, use $X  =\mathbb{N}$ and $Y = \{0,1\}$ to see the differences (both in their usual order).

Comment: One is has limit points, one doesn't? Right?

Comment: @fosho limit points is not an order concept. One is order isomorphic to $X$ the other is not.

Comment: I thought limit point is an order concept, here by a limit point I mean a point $x$ that is not minimal and for any $y<x$ there exists $z$ such that $y<z$ and $z<x$. Such points are preserved by order isomorphism? E.g. (0,1) is a limit point in the example using the anti-lex order. It's also not hard to see the example using the lex order has no limit points.

Comment: @fosho yes all $(n,0)$ lie before $(0,1)$ anti-lexwise.

Comment: Is antilex order X×Y isomorphic to lex order Y×X?

Comment: @WilliamElliot  that’s almost immediate yes.